# Round columns based on second level of MultiColumn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a table which looks like this:

```
>>> df.head()
Out[13]: 
                                v                   u                      
                             init    change  integral      init    change   
     foo          bar                                                     
baseline          NaN    0.025054  0.858122  0.017930  0.048435  1.091943   
       a          10.0   0.025042  0.856307  0.017546  0.047815  1.100351   
                  50.0   0.025008  0.856681  0.010052  0.048252  1.056658   
       b          1.0    0.025045  0.858044  0.015635  0.047135  1.091384   
                  2.0    0.025048  0.855388  0.016115  0.047324  1.087964
```

Now I would like to select columns based on the label of the second level of the column, and round them.

I can access them using `xs`: `df.xs('init', 1, 1)`. However, I naturally cannot use `xs` to replace the values:

```
>>> df.xs('init', 1, 1) = df.xs('init', 1, 1).round(decimals=3)
  File "<ipython-input-12-47c16e5011a3>", line 1
    df.xs('init', 1, 1) = df.xs('init', 1, 1).round(decimals=3)
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

What's the way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4),
                  ['a', 'b'],
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['One', 'Two']]))

df
```

[image]

Use `pd.IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Two']] *= 3

df
```

[image]

In this case `pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Two']` is specifying all elements from the first level and `'Two'` from the second level.  Using `loc` allows us to assign to `df`.